Can I create a columnstore table in singlestore if the default table type setting is rowstore? If so, what will be the syntax?
I'm currently working with singlestoredb. default storage type for my db is rowstore.
I wanted to know if I can create columnstore tables if default_table_type is set as "rowstore" in my DB. What should be the syntax for it?
I tried researching syntax for creating columnstore table by explicitly mentioning columnstore in the script but I could not find any.

You can create a columnstore table in SingleStore even though your default table type is rowstore.
All you need to do is to include the keyword SORT KEY(column name which you want ) in your create table DDL.
Example:
CREATE TABLE products (
     ProductId INT,
     Color VARCHAR(10),
     Price INT,
     Qty INT,
     SORT KEY (Price),
     SHARD KEY (ProductId)
);

You can query the table information_schema.tables on the same to verify if your table is indeed rowstore or columnstore.
select table_name,storage_type from information_schema.tables;
Please refer to this document for more detailed information on the same.
